# Stability of matrix eigenspaces under small pertubations

Tags: linear-algebra

For any a complex $n\times n$-matrix $A$, denote it's $\lambda$-eigenspace by $E_{A,\lambda}$. Now, fix some matrix $A$ and suppose we have a continuous function $f: I \rightarrow \operatorname{Mat}(n\times n, \mathbb{C})$ such that $f(0)=A$ and each $f(t)$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$.

Is it possible to find some small neighbourhood $J$ of $0$ such that for each $t \in J$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, we have $E_{f(t),\lambda} \cong E_{A,\lambda}$? More precisely, $E_{f(t),\lambda} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^n \twoheadrightarrow E_{A,\lambda}$ should be an isomorphism for the canonical inclusion and projection.

I'm inclined to think that this is true: If we let $E_{A,\lambda}$ be spanned by - for the sake of simplicity - $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and complete to a basis $v, v_2, \ldots v_n$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $E_{f(t),\lambda}$ should be spanned by $v + \sum f_i(t)v_i$ for functions $f_i$ continuous in $t$ and vanishing in $0$. However, the proof (if the statement is actually true) eludes me. Any help is appreciated!